# Using boost::assign::list_of

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

This compiles:

```
std::vector<int> value = boost::assign::list_of(1)(2);
```

But not this:

```
Constructor(std::vector<int> value)
{
}

Constructor (boost::assign::list_of(1)(2));
```

Is there a one-liner solution for initializing the vector passed to the constructor?

Better still, if the constructor copies to a class variable by taking a reference instead:

```
Constructor(std::vector<int>& value)
{
    _value = value;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I try the following:

```
enum Foo
{
    FOO_ONE, FOO_TWO 
};

class Constructor
{
public:
    Constructor(const std::vector<Foo>& value){}
};

Constructor c(std::vector<Foo>(boost::assign::list_of(FOO_ONE)));
```

I get the compiler error:

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Foo
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Foo
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Comment: Can you give the compiler error message?

Comment: @Kevin MOLCARD Added compiler error

Comment: [Looks like this is the bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7364).

Comment: have you tried `Constructor c(boost::assign::list_of<std::vector<Foo>>(FOO_ONE));`

Answer (score 20):

This is a annoying problem, we also had some time before. We fixed it by using the `convert_to_container` method:

```
Constructor c(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2).convert_to_container<std::vector<int> >() );
```

There are more issues with **std::list** using in constructor too. See [Pass std::list to constructor using boost's list_of doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135896/pass-stdlist-to-constructor-using-boosts-list-of-doesnt-compile) for the appropriate answer.

Comment: Did you discover why it is neccessary to call `conver_to_container` function?

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this template to make temporary instance of std::vector in-place:

```
#include <vector>
namespace Util {
//init vector
template <typename ELEMENT_TYPE > struct vector_of
    : public std::vector<ELEMENT_TYPE>
{
    vector_of(const ELEMENT_TYPE& t)
    {
        (*this)(t);
    }
    vector_of& operator()(const ELEMENT_TYPE& t)
    {
        this->push_back(t);
        return *this;
    }
};
}//namespace Util
```

Usage would look like this:

```
Constructor (Util::vector_of<int>(1)(2));
```

Constructor signature would look like this:

```
Constructor(const std::vector<int>& value)
{
    _value = value;
}
```