# Populating a list of strings into a vector in pre C++11

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring, c++03

Firstly, I'd like to apologise if this is a blinding simple and obvious question. I know it's a fairly easy one to people with the know-how. C++11 allows vectors to be initialised in list form:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {
    "this is a",
    "list of strings",
    "which are going",
    "to be stored",
    "in a vector"};
```

But this isn't available in older versions. I've been trying to think of the best way to populate a vector of strings and so far the only thing I can really come up with is:

```
std::string s1("this is a");
std::string s2("list of strings");
std::string s3("which are going");
std::string s4("to be stored");
std::string s5("in a vector");

std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back(s1);
v.push_back(s2);
v.push_back(s3);
v.push_back(s4);
v.push_back(s5);
```

It works, but it's a bit of a chore to write and I'm convinced there's a better way.

Comment: Use an array to initialize it. You should be able to find examples on tutorials to `std::vector`.

Comment: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231491/how-to-initialize-const-stdvectort-like-a-c-array/231495#231495

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical way is to define `begin()` and `end()` functions in a suitable header and use something like this:

```
char const* array[] = {
    "this is a",
    "list of strings",
    "which are going",
    "to be stored",
    "in a vector"
};
std::vector<std::string> vec(begin(array), end(array));
```

The functions `begin()` and `end()` are defined like this:

```
template <typename T, int Size>
T* begin(T (&array)[Size]) {
    return array;
}
template <typename T, int Size>
T* end(T (&array)[Size]) {
    return array + Size;
}
```

Comment: @NemanjaBoric: of course, I'm using `begin()` and `end()`! As far as I know I was the first who described this technique publicly at some point in the [last millennium](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/0Pr5ecSTwZw). These function templates were also one of first [Boost contributions](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/BFROOT/dist/packages/boost/V01-27-00-04/libs/array_traits/array_traits.html).

Comment: Just for the benefit of people like me, who weren't aware of this, this capability now appears to be in the [Boost.Range library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that it is perfectly forward-compatible with C++11. It is even possible to wrap this in macros so that it [looks as if initializing](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/wiki?name=Features/Extras#cxxo-i12n) a C-array (and that can be made C++11-compatible as well): `SOME_WRAPPER(vector<string> vec) = {"this is a", "list of strings", ...., };`

Comment: Yes, it's also [in the iterator library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) in C++11.

Answer (score 4):

As chris noted, you could store all literals into the array, and then initialize vector from that array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
        const char* data[] = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3"};
        std::vector<std::string> vec(data, data + sizeof(data)/sizeof(const char*));
}
```

You don't need explicit conversion to `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're "stuck" with pre-C++11 C++, there are only a couple of alternatives and they're not necessarily "better".

First, you can create an array of constant C strings and copy them into the vector. You might save a little typing, but then you have a copy loop in there.

Second, if you can use boost, you could [use boost::assign's list_of as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285272/using-boostassignlist-of).